# How to set the custom tooltip label in Jfree PieChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, jfreereport

In my `JfreeChart`, the label formats are `{0}, {1}, {2}`.

Here `{0}` represents the pie section key, `{1}` represents the section value and `{2}` represents the percentage.

I am setting the label in piechart by using the following code

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{1}"));
```

Lets assume chart has 2 sections. the `value({1})` of the 1st section is 200 and second section is 150. My requirement is like this one:

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{1}" * 3));
```

Can any one please tell how to modify this value?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the value in the tooltip to be three times larger.  Update the value in the actual chart and use {1} by itself in the generator.

If you really want to just update the label you will have to create your own `PieSectionLabelGenerator` that formats the results exactly as you need them.

If you need a new format look at the API as `StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator` has constructors that take in multiple formats.  (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator.html)

Comment: The value is milliseconds. I want to show it in Date Format. How to achieve this one?